# Tool for gcc GIMPLE modification?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-gcc

I need to add to gcc support of an OpenMP-like (directive) language. I know it is possible to dump GIMPLE code and then "undump" it and continue compilation. I want to modify the dumped DIMPLE to add calls of my dynamic library, modify variables, and so on.  Is there any handy tool to do this?

**EDIT:**  Perhaps LLVM is what I need. Currently I am interested in how to transform GIMPLE to LLVM IR.  Also, is there a way to get information what line of source code corresponds to concrete operator of IR?

Comment: Doesn't the gcc frontend for LLVM do just that, that is, have the gcc compiler generate code in LLVM Bytecode format.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you exactly need, you might be able to do this using [GCC Plugins](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/plugins).

Comment: thanks Amir, but it seems that only MELT fits my needs and i have reasons not to use it: 1. lisp isn't good for me 2. it's unripe

Comment: MELT is an existing GCC plugin. But instead, you could consider developing your own GCC plugin to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

GIMPLE => LLVM IR translator is called "llvm-gcc" (or DragonEgg if you want a GCC plugin).
The standard way of storing the map between lines of source language and something in LLVM IR is via emission of the debug information.